# jQuery - fire event after element is loaded

Tags: jquery, load

I have to edit an existing web application. My problem is that I don't have the permission to edit the scripts from the application itself. I just got an custom.js.

A little bit background information about the webapp. It generates some HTML elements via ajax i guess (minified JS). My task is to hide one of those elements. My problem is here that when i try to hide it from my custom.js, it isn't generated yet. So my question is, is the a nice way, to wait until the element is loaded?

What I tried already:

```
$(document).on("load", ".testLoad", function() {
    console.log('Finally loaded');
});
```

Unfortunately this isn't working for me.

```
setTimeout(function(){
        $('.testLoad').hide();
    }, 5000);
```

This is working, but not the cleanest solution.

Comment: You have to provide relevant code generating this DIV because for this type of element, there is no `load` event (doesn't make sense)

Comment: @A.Wolff As I said, the code for the generated DIV is minified in a JS. Let's just say, the use something like that: `$('body').prepend('<div class="testLoad">Testing Load</div>');`

Answer (score 2):

In your case either you can setup a mutation observer or you can make use of `.ajaxComplete()` method:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
  if (settings.url === "the/url/") { // you can check the url which is causing 
    console.log('Finally loaded');         // the new elements to be created.
  }
});
```

Comment: Ya binding a global ajax event would be a quite interresting alternative to the mutation observer imho

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this. Unfortunately i get a lot of url's back, but most of them have a token. So i guess i have no chance to find out which url is the correct one. Do you have a good link, tutorial for the mutation observer?

Comment: @Sylnois https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver check this link.

Comment: @Sylnois But has condition, instead of checking for URL, you could just check if element already exists and then unbind this event: `if($('.testLoad').length) {$('.testLoad').hide(); $(this).off('ajaxcomplete');}` That's said, regarding your posted code, if you want just to hide element, why not just use CSS??? `.testLoad { display: none;}` I guess your posted code was just an example but need to be said

Comment: Thank you guys. Seems to work. Now i just have to test it the right way :)